# Invalid or Unqualified Reference

Tags: excel, vba

Do I need to put in the sheet name? I need to use this macro across multiple workbooks with similar worksheets but the tab names are different.

```
Sub pageSetup()
ActiveSheet.pageSetup
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1#)

End Sub
```

Comment: Missing `With` and `End with`

Answer (score 4):

As Tim has not claimed his answer, you could use either of the following two options to either

- format the `ActiveSheet`
- format all `WorkSheets` in the `ActiveWorkBook`

**ActiveSheet**

```
Sub TimWilliamsPoints()
With ActiveSheet.pageSetup
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1#)
End With
End Sub
```

**All Sheets**

```
Sub TimWilliamsPoints2()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
With ws.pageSetup
.Orientation = xlLandscape
.PaperSize = xlPaperLegal
.FitToPagesWide = 1
.FitToPagesTall = 1
.LeftMargin = Application.InchesToPoints(1#)
End With
Next ws
End Sub
```