# Excel VBA, Invalid Qualifier, Array.Rank

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

In the below code, `nX = xMat.Rank` returns the error "Invalid qualifier." Why? I'm using Excel 2010's built-in VBA editor:

```
Public Function polyReg(ByRef x() As Double, ByRef y() As Double) As Double()
  ' =============================
  Dim nX, nY, i, j As Integer
  Dim xMat() As Double
  nX = UBound(x)
  nY = UBound(y)
  ReDim xMat(1 To nX, 1 To order)
  ' =============================
  For i = 1 To order
    For j = 1 To nX
      xMat(j, i) = 1
    Next j
  Next i
  ' =============================
  nX = xMat.Rank
  ' =============================
  polyReg = y
  ' =============================
End Function
```

I looked at a few related posts that failed to address my concern:

[Invalid Qualifier for String.Add in Outlook VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17032589/invalid-qualifier-for-string-add-in-outlook-vba)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7889653/invalid-qualifier-error-in-vba

[Invalid or Unqualified Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13828796/invalid-or-unqualified-reference)

I have not found an answer to my question in Excel's VBA documentation.

Comment: Check the VBA inbuilt help on what `.Rank` does. Use `WorksheetFunction.Rank Method` to check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a VB expert. If my answer below is incorrect, someone please notify me:

Visual Basic <> Visual Basic for Applications (Excel)... This is a hard lesson for me to learn. The Array.Rank function [exists in VB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.rank(v=vs.90).aspx) but [does not exist in VBA (Excel)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/152288). What. A. Shame.

I'm tempted to ask another question with a similar answer, just because I know it will confound other programmers unfamiliar with VB and VBA. Is there any policy against asking questions to which you know the answer? (Topic of theoretical question: Try/Catch? Only VB. VBA (Excel) uses On Error.)

Comment: You're answer is correct.  Array's and strings are not objects in VBA and do not have member functions.  Get used to disappointment.
Answering your own question is encouraged if you found a solution.  Asking a question that you know the answer to is ok (check Meta-Stackoverflow first) as long as it hasn't already been asked.